# Averaging Time values in Excel - Format mm:ss

Tags: excel, time, formula

I'm trying to determine the average ice time for hockey players on a team.  Each player plays a certain amount of time in a game, 25:15 means a player plays an average of 25 minutes and 15 seconds each game (clearly a defensemen!).  So I have a column of times formatted as such and have not been able to determine a formula to get the average of these values.  If one guy plays 25:15 and another 19:15, I need to get the value 22:15 for the average for these two players.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using the wrong time format. If you select "Time" from the format dropdown, then you're actually selecting a time of day (e.g. 25:15 actually represents 1:15 AM). Instead, select "More Number Formats..." and then select "Custom." From there you should be able to select "[h]:mm:ss **see example image" 
Apply that format to all your time values and your =AVERAGE() cell.

Comment: I don't know why mm:ss doesn't work, but [h]:mm:ss does!  It still displays 25:15:00 in the cell, and 1/1/1900  1:15:00 AM in the formula bar, but the calculation is correct, and result displayed properly!  Thanks very much Sawyer!

Answer (score 0):

With 25:15 in A1 and 19:15 in A2 try somewhere else on the sheet:

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That's what I started with, and still have not been able to make it work.  I know I need to use average, just can't get it to work with any format I've chosen, may need to convert seconds to decimal and just work in minutes.